# Can't emit exist property in array from model

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to emit `name` property of an array called `Model[]` generated from my Model.ts file.When I try to emit this to use on my app.component,it says property 'name' does not exist on type `Model[]`.That's weird because `name:string` property exists on my model.ts.Maybe I think wrong and there's another mistake can you help me to solve this and what's the mistake exactly?

**Model.ts**

```
export class Model
{
   name:string;
   constructor(name:string)
   {
       this.name=name;
   }
}
```

**favorite.component.ts**

```
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
  items:Model[]= [new Model('Page-1'),new Model('Page-2'),new Model('Page-3')];
  @Output() myArray = new EventEmitter<Model>();
  //@Output() featureSelected=new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() { }
   onSelect()
   {
    // console.log(feature);
    this.myArray.emit(this.items.name); //mistake is here on this parameter.
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**favorite.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li  *ngFor="let item of items">
          <a href="#" (click)="onSelect('[item.name]')">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this.items is an array. You will have to give index such as this.items[0].name .. show me your template of fav component such that can help in better way

Comment: @debugmode I added that template.There's a navbar on the top and elements of navbar comes from array.Array defined on favorite-component and I'm trying to pass to the app-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your html, pass the  item to your onSelect method.

```
<li  *ngFor="let item of items">
  <a href="#" (click)="onSelect(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

In your component.ts :

```
onSelect(modelItemSelected: Model)
{
  this.myArray.emit(modelItemSelected); //mistake is here on this parameter.
}
```

To address your thoughts :

> it says property 'name' does not exist on type Model[]

Yes, your property *'name'* exists on type **Model**, but it doesn't exist on type **Model[]** which is an array of **Model**.

Comment: It doesn't work.Still insist to give same error that's not defined as string in Model

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek i updated, your `EventEmitter` is of type `Model`, not string. so y ou need to passe an item

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the rest of your code but you'll need the array index.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li  *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
          <a href="#" (click)="onSelect(i)">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
  items:Model[]= [new Model('Page-1'),new Model('Page-2'),new Model('Page-3')];
  @Output() myArray = new EventEmitter<Model>();
  //@Output() featureSelected=new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() { }
   onSelect(index:number)
   {
    // console.log(feature);
    this.myArray.emit(this.items[index].name); //mistake is here on this parameter.
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep these two points in mind

1. If you wish to emit name then change type of the EventEmitter from
   Model to string or emit the Model type and read name property in the
   parent component
2. You have to find particular item in array to item. I have hard coded it to index  [0], however you can select any index depending on your use case.

   ```
   export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {

   items: Model[] = [
   new Model('Page-1'),
   new Model('Page-2'),
   new Model('Page-3')
   ];
     @Output() myArray = new EventEmitter<Model>();
     @Output() selectedmodelname = new EventEmitter<string>();
    constructor() { }
    onSelect() {
       this.myArray.emit(this.items[0]);
       this.selectedmodelname.emit(this.items[0].name);
     }
     ngOnInit() {
     }
   ```

I hope it helps.